# Removing posts by sql

Tags: sql

Often i build a site and we have test posts. I was wondering if there's a way via sql to drop all the blog posts with a simple sql query.

Obviously, I would have backed up my previous database before truncating these tables.

I would like to leave the pages alone if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off doing this with wordpress functions and adding a button which would delete all posts (or even having a shortcode that, when loaded, would do it). The reason I recommend doing this instead of SQL directly is that [`wp_delete_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) will take all the associated meta with it, which saves you having to do complicated SQL. You can combine this with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get posts given a complex set of desired parameters and then loop through them to remove them.